# Google AIY Kit Button Trigger

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I completed the Google AIY Kit by following the included instruction manual. However, the button does not Trigger the Google Assistant like in the videos, only saying "Ok Google" will do the trick. The button does blink to indicate that it is on and turns solid when I say "Ok Google". In which directory/file are triggers located, and what code would allow me to get the button to trigger the assistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. Sharing for anyone that might run into the same issue. 
The directory /home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src contains four python scripts. The instructions say to use assistant_library_demo.py with the dev terminal. To get the button working, you actually need to use assistant_library_with_button_demo.py . This will allow you to trigger the assistant by using the hotword "Ok Google" and by just pressing the button.